# async load and prepend the content of a file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to prepend the content of `imgt.php` to `bb`.

Seems there is no direct way, so I tried to load the content firstly to another div (`store`) and then prepend it to `bb`

This works **only on second click**, the first click doesn't work.

Obviously there is a problem with `async` protocol.

Any help?

```
async function get_img_top(){
    await $('#store').load('def/imgt.php');
    let ht = $('#store').html();
    $('#bb').prepend(ht);
}

$(document).on('click', '.atitle', function(){
    get_img_top();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery's [.load()](https://api.jquery.com/load/) is not asynchronous so you cannot await it. You can however supply .load() with a complete callback function.

```
function get_img_top() {
  $('#store').load('def/imgt.php', function() {
    let ht = $('#store').html();
    $('#bb').prepend(ht);
  });
}

$(document).on('click', '.atitle', function() {
  get_img_top();
});
```